# What did Vegeta mean with "be careful Kakaroto, that could be the super saiyajin true form!"?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

In Dragon Ball Super episode 100, (spoiler)

> After Kale transformed in green super saiyajin "berserker", Vegeta says to Goku: "be careful Kakaroto, that could be the super saiyajin true form!"

What did he mean with this? was he refering to

> the legendary super saiyajin?

or was he talking about something else?

Comment: I just thought that he was referring to her actual fighting form instead of her base, but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He was referring to the legendary super saiyan form. It is the Legendary Super Saiyan form that Broly basically used, but I thought he wasn't canon so I am not really sure how Vegeta can refer to the form Broly used. However he probably as the Saiyan prince posses more knowledge than others when it came to being a super saiyan. By calling it the true form he most likely verbally meant to the form giving an infinite amount of stamina. The form Kale used was Berserker Super Saiyan though.

Legendary Super Saiyan: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Super_Saiyan

Berserker/Uncontrollable Super Saiyan: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker_Super_Saiyan